# Hazelcast Operation Heartbeat Timeouts appearing sporadically

Tags: java, hazelcast

We have a Hazelcast client (3.7.4):

```
//Initializes Hazelcast client config
ClientConfig aHazelcastClientConfig = new ClientConfig();
String aHazelcastUrl = this.getHost()+":"+this.getPort().toString();

ClientNetworkConfig aHazelcastNetworkConfig= 
aHazelcastClientConfig.getNetworkConfig();
aHazelcastNetworkConfig.addAddress(aHazelcastUrl);

GroupConfig group = new  GroupConfig (getGroupName(),getGroupPassword());       
aHazelcastClientConfig.setGroupConfig(group);

HazelcastInstance aHazelcastClient=
HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient(aHazelcastClientConfig);
...
IMap aMonitoredMap = aHazelcastClient.getMap(getMonitoredMap());
```

that periodically checks one HZ Server (3.7.4), and we have observed sometimes next exceptions are appearing in the client side:

*InitializeDistributedObjectOperation invocation failed to complete due to operation-heartbeat-timeout. Current time: 2017-02-07 18:07:30.329. Total elapsed time: 120189 ms. Last operation heartbeat: never. Last operation heartbeat from member: 2017-02-07 18:05:37.489. Invocation{op=com.hazelcast.spi.impl.proxyservice.impl.operations.InitializeDistributedObjectOperation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', identityHash=9759664, partitionId=-1, replicaIndex=0, callId=0, invocationTime=1486487130140 (2017-02-07 18:05:30.140), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=60000}, tryCount=1, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeoutMillis=60000, firstInvocationTimeMs=1486487130140, firstInvocationTime='2017-02-07 18:05:30.140', lastHeartbeatMillis=0, lastHeartbeatTime='1970-01-01 01:00:00.000', target=[10.118.152.82]:5720, pendingResponse={VOID}, backupsAcksExpected=0, backupsAcksReceived=0, connection=Connection[id=7, /172.22.191.200:5720->/10.118.152.82:42563, endpoint=[10.118.152.82]:5720, alive=true, type=MEMBER]}*

It seems the maximum call waiting timeout (by default 60000 msecs) is being reached. In the above example, the total elapsed time is more than 2 minutes (120189 ms)

This problem is appearing sporadically, without any regular appearance pattern.
It seems the network is working correctly when it has appeared, so we can discard some network connectivity issue.

Any hint or recommendation about which reasons could provoke it?

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards,
Jorge

Comment: Jorge; does a specific operation timeout or all operations timeout? And I understand you have a single member in your cluster, is that correct?

Comment: Got the same issue with two members, multicast detection, v3.7.1. Results in split-brain fpr some minutes and a bit later they merge again. As its unpredictable for now we had to add a second layer of a simplistic database-semaphore. Would love to get some insight :)